# Link containers env

Tags: docker, docker-container

Im trying to link two containers to one app, and want to reference those apps hostname/url in an env.

Then the main application can run, but i cannot manage to get the values properly.

Dockerfile of main app contains this

```
ENV APP1_URL app1

ENV APP2_URL app2
```

When running

```
docker run -d -p 22222:3000 --link app1:app1 app2:app2 --name mainapp user/image
```

Main app needs those env to run, how can i get those values?

Comment: `app1_url=$(docker exec -it container_id echo $APP1_URL)` same logic for the second one, and then `docker run -e app1=$app1_url` and so

Comment: This would depend on the language of your main app, but in general these are just like any other environment variables

Comment: if you get inside the main app ... docker exec -it mainapp bash ... and then run the linux command ... env ... what environment vairables do you see, any you need?

Comment: actually i was trying to replace an env var of my app with the one that docker generates during the linking (in the dockerfile), but couldnt figure out how... I ended using docker env generated ones... such as app_port_addr...